# Why does a value suddenly become nil?

Tags: ios, swift, image

I'm working on a project where I want to get an image for a particular identifier. I have the following function:

```
func imageForIdentifier(identifier: String?) -> UIImage? {
        if identifier == nil || identifier! == "" {
            return nil
        }
        let directory = directoryForID(identifier!)
        if let img = imgInCache.objectForKey(identifier!) as? UIImage {
            return img
        }
        if let img = NSData(contentsOfFile: directory) {
            return UIImage(data: img)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

...and the `directoryForID` function...

```
func directoryForID(identifier: String) -> String {
        let directoryPath: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentationDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first!
        return (directoryPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(identifier).path!)
    }
```

If I pass an image identifier it should create a directory and in the last if-Statement it should return a `UIImage` of the data from this directory. However it skips all of the if-Statements and returns nil. How is this possible even though I pass a correct identifier?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Appending a path component to the result of `URLsForDirectory` does not create a directory automatically. You have to write the code. And your method is a great example for using `guard` rather than `if`

Comment: A guard statement would be OK, but it would be even better if the routine wasn't trying to take an optional as an argument.  As a general rule you shouldn't pass optionals as arguments.  Instead the caller should have to decide, in it's own context, how to resolve the optional.

Comment: Where you say it should "create a directory" I assume you mean that it should create a URL representing a directory?  Nothing in your code is actually going to result in a directory being created.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is  how you are testing the *nil-ability* or *emptiness* of the string object **identifier**:

identifier.length can be helpful to validate the content of the identifier...

Comment: Even better than `identifier.length` you could use `identifier.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer.

```
func imageForIdentifier(identifier: String?) -> UIImage? {

    guard let identifier else { return }

    let directory = directoryForID(identifier)
    if let img = imgInCache.objectForKey(identifier) as? UIImage {
        return img
    }
    if let img = NSData(contentsOfFile: directory) {
        return UIImage(data: img)
    }
    return nil
}
```